# Custom Object Collection as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In c# I can do this:

```
   public class Widget{
      public int value1;
      public int value2;
   }
```

and elsewhere define a list of Widgets:

```
   pulbic List<Widget> widgets = new List<Widget>();
```

Is it possible to make a list of Widgets in actionscript or am I stuck with jamming all the widgets into an array collection and casting each item when I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Vector` class:

```
public var widgets:Vector.<Widget> = new Vector.<Widget>();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

**update** In case you need a `ListCollectionView`, respectively an `ICollectionView` and/or `IList`, check out David Beale's `VectorCollection`.

http://www.bealearts.co.uk/blog/category/vectorcollection/

Comment: Even though vector can help you by providing the type, it is not as powerful as that of the Arraycollection. You may have to add the elements back to the array collection to utilize all the features.

Comment: @Zeus While this is true, an `ArrayCollection` cannot be typed AFAIK. One could extend `ArrayCollection` and use a metadata tag on the overridden `source` property, however metadata type checks only apply to MXML code at compile time. Maybe I'm wrong and that's what he's planning to do, but somehow to me his question sounds as if he's talking about ActionScript usage.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way of doing this, using metadata.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html